# What mode of SPI is the standard if nothing regarding the mode is mentioned in the slave datasheet?

Tags: spi, sdcard

I am trying to bit bang SPI for a SD Card, I went through [this SD Card datasheet](http://www.convict.lu/pdf/ProdManualSDCardv1.9.pdf) and I couldn't find any information regarding the mode that needs to be used. If I missed, please point it out.

Else what mode would be standard if nothing is mentioned? What CPOL and phase should I use?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to pull out that information from 3.4.5, the bus timing figure?

Comment: What do you mean by Mode ? if it's line polarity (active high/low) it's on the figure Figure 3-6.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Kinda confusing because regarding the phase, sampling and transitioning takes place on edges, that is what I know but this image says that the data should be set up before the rising edge and should be changed after rising edge. That is what I conclude.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Ok. Mode 2 is my guess?

Comment: @Damien I believe that is regarding the voltage level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the datasheet you link to
[image]

The timing diagram at 3.4.5 shows that the clock idles low (CPOL=0), and that out changes on the clock trailing edge and in gets read on the rising edge (CPHA=0), which is SPI mode 0.

Comment: Thanks, Honestly I absolutely missed this diagram and was searching in the text if it is mentioned somewhere. This was a nice lesson @ reading datasheet